# displaying images in browserfield when passing HTML string in Blackberry

Tags: html, blackberry, java-me

I'm reading a HTML file from SDCard with browserfield (API 5.0)

```
BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_NONE);
browser = new BrowserField(config);
browser.displayContent(content); // content (from file) = "<html><head>..."
```

I can't just find a way to inform the browserfield that the images in this page are sitting next to the HTML file in the images directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can pass a parameter to `browser.displayContent(content, path)`, `path` parameter tells the browser where to look for relative paths in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

That is an interesting problem. I haven't tackled that issue yet, but what I would suggest you try is extending BrowserFieldConnectionManager and rewriting makeRequest() so that it recognizes a request for one of the locally stored resources and returns an InputConnection to it.

Comment: Seems like a good solution, I think I'll be using it in the near future, but I found that I can pass a parameter to `browser.displayContent(content, path)`, `path` parameter tells the browser where to look for relative paths in the HTML.

Comment: Good solution. You should write it up as an answer and accept it.